# How to switch large document from units-package to siunitx?

Tags: siunitx, units

For historical reasons, I've been using the `units` package in my thesis to typeset numbers with units or units with `\usepackage[tight]{units}`

For formatting numbers in table columns I'm already using the `siunitx` package and I'd also like to use it for the numbers with units and units.
However in the large document (>300 pages) I can not replace all (>500) occurences of the `\unit[]{}`command by hand.

What is a good strategy for replacing the old commands with new ones?

I assume it is not sufficient to replace `\unit[` by `\SI[` or is the "syntax" of optional arguments and arguments "compatible" for both commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `units` package is quite easy to emulate reasonably. I'd recommend using the LaTeX3 `\DeclareDocumentCommand` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-weight, per-mode = fraction}
\DeclareDocumentCommand\unit{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\si{#2}}{\SI{#1}{#2}}%
}
\begin{document}
\unit{m}
\unit[10]{m}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph! 2 questions: 1) Are you sure, that this will give comparable results like the original `\unit` command, if I just use their arguments with `\si` or ´\SI`? Could there be any cases where it does not work? 2) I'm using "standard" LaTeX which is IMHO a version <3 (`LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>`). Can I just use the LaTeX3-macro then?

Comment: You can use LaTeX3 macros if you load suitable packages, in this case `xparse`, I guess; however, this is loaded by `siunitx` anyway, so you don't have to declare it (although doing so might be a good practice imho).  See http://www.latex-project.org/latex3.html for more info on LaTeX3.

Comment: @Martin: This is the approach I took in v1 of `\siunitx`, where a lot of testing did look okay. Currently, 'LaTeX3' means the `expl3` layer on top of LaTeX2e. `siunitx` loads the `expl3` layer, so you should have no issues.

Answer (score 6):

Since the syntax for **units** is `\unit[<value>]{<unit>}`, one has to use two different commands of **siunitx**:

```
\makeatletter
\let\unit\relax % to "undefine" it
\DeclareRobustCommand{\unit}{\@ifnextchar[\my@si\si}
\def\my@si[#1]#2{\SI{#1}{#2}}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively

```
\makeatletter
\let\unit\relax % to "undefine" it
\DeclareRobustCommand{\unit}[2][]{%
   \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax % check if optional argument is empty
     % no value
     \si{#2}%
   \else
     % value is given
     \SI{#1}{#2}
   \fi}
 \makeatother
```

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely do it using regular expressions.  You'd have it without macro trickery (which isn't always what one wants) and - as an additional bonus - you'd learn to use a powerful tool.

In Emacs (this is kind of important, since emacs', perl's etc. regexps are sometimes slightly different) I'd use the following transformations (using `query-replace-regexp`):

```
\\unit\[\(.+?\)\]{\(.+?\)}    ->    \\SI{\1}{\2}
```

and

```
\\unit{\(.+?\)}    ->    \\si{\1}
```

This assumes that you have no `]`'s in the optional argument and no `}`'s in the mandatory one; if you have nested constructs etc., you'll have to either:

- use egreg's approach;
- concoct a more clever regexp to do it automatically;
- (my favourite) first create a regexp to *find* such cases automatically and *correct* them manually (assuming that such cases are rather rare, of course).

Notice that in the very first regexp, instead of `.+?`, you could use something more specific, like `[0-9.]+` (assuming you have only raw numbers, which is probably the case); then you wouldn't need the question mark, which denotes a so-called *non-greedy* operator (consume as few characters as possible instead of as many).

A concluding remark is that while regexps seem terrifying at first sight, believe me that once you get hang of them, your life will be easier.